# java telnet socket client

Tags: java

Hi guys i've written a simple telnet socket client in java and i'm trying to connect to the telnet services on localhost within windows 7 Pro. The code is executing fine but it is failing to printout out the the output stream and input stream instead the code trow  the following exception:
Attemping to connect to host localhost on port 1024
Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: localhost

Is there something that i'm missing ??? THE CODE IS BELOW
Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class telnetClients {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String telnetServer = new String ("localhost");
    int port = 1024;
    if (args.length > 0)
       telnetServer = args[0];
    System.out.println ("Attemping to connect to host " +
            telnetServer + " on port "
                + port);

    Socket ClientSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    try {
        ClientSocket = new Socket(telnetServer, port);
            ClientSocket.setSoTimeout(20000);
          //    PrintStream com = new PrintStream(ClientSocket.getOutputStream());
          //    System.out.println(com);
           //    BufferedReader inCom = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader                (ClientSocket.getInputStream()));


        out = new PrintWriter(ClientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        System.out.println(out);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    ClientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String command = in.readLine();
        if(in != null);
        System.out.println(in);

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + telnetServer);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                           + "the connection to: " + telnetServer);
        System.exit(1);
    }

BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(System.in));
              String userInput;

    System.out.println ("Type Message (\"bye\" to quit)");
while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) 
       {
    out.println(userInput);

        // end loop
        if (userInput.equals("bye"))
            break;

    System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
   }

out.close();
in.close();
stdIn.close();
ClientSocket.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps rather than ignoring what the exception is, you should print it (`e.printStackTrace()`). It'll tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Is that service enabled on your machine?

Comment: "Couldn't get I/O for the connection" is not an exception. It is just something you printed out yourself when you *caught* the exception. It is useless. What you should have printed out was the *exception* itself. Then you would know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

sample for you which worked for me

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "hostname";
    int port = 8080;
    try (Socket pingSocket = new Socket(url, port)) {
      try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(pingSocket.getOutputStream(), true); BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pingSocket.getInputStream()));) {
        out.println("ping");
        System.out.println("Telnet Success: " + in.readLine());
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Telnet Fail: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think that your problem is probably that the Telnet service is not enabled. In Windows 7 you can check this in Programs and Features (Control Panel) under Windows features.

After that you have to configure the port because the default port por a TCP connection is 23. You can do this with `tlntadmn [\\server] config port=PortNumber`